# What can we do about questions remaining for days on the Unanswered tab?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

It would be nice to process the [Unanswered Tab](https://superuser.com/unanswered) on a daily basis...

However, it feels like I am the only one passing by there, which is why there is barely any progress there.

What can we do such that we make progress so that questions that need their answers get answered?

Comment: This topic inspired my two most recent answers. Thanks for reminding me about this view!

Answer (score 2):

The default tab is [votes] and [no answers] also has this problem.

However, I found out that when I put to **newest** that this is a way more efficient way to handle this tab; as users don't come back after a while answering the previous tab is not really feasible and thus it is better to focus on *the current moment in time*.